# Generating a SOAP client with Apache CXF 3.1.1

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

To generate my client code, I used the follow command:

```
wsdl2java -client HelloWorld.wsdl
```

This generated the java files and it's working without errors but, unfortunately, very slowly, two seconds for each call.

In [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/), the same Web service method is called in 200ms.

I noticed on the logs that the `org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL` is being called each time I call a service. This seems the software are recreating the client from the WSDL each time. This happens even when I keep my service objects created.

How can I stop this? What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the problem.

Each time I call `MyService.getPort()`, the WSDL is parsed. 
So, I create this `port` just once and reuse it through my application.

Now the client is really fast!